# how to get a list of values from user input in ocaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

i cannot find a way to get a list from values given by the user i already made a function insert that inserts a value in a list but i don't know how to get the values from the user here is my code containing 4 examples A1,..,A4 of variables id like to get from the user

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read_line` to get the input from the user in a string, then use Str module to split it.

In `utop` (note that the user inputs "1 2 3 4" thx to `read_line()`)

```
 #require "str";;
 #read_line() |> Str.split (Str.regexp " +") |> List.map int_of_string;;
 1 2 3 4
 - : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]  
 #
```

You can then use more sophisticated regexp to split your input (to manage comma, semi-colon, ...)

[related to the 2nd comment] , let' s say you want to split the string '"(5, 3, 5) (4,3,5)"' to triplet of integer, you first split according to the parenthesis (first instance of split below), then for each group, you split according to the elements you need :

```
  Str.split (Str.regexp ")") s |> 
  List.map (fun x -> Str.split (Str.regexp "[(, ]+") x |>
            List.map int_of_string) ;;
```

In the case the elements do not have all the same type, you need a function that takes a list as input and translate it to a tuple).

Comment: i read a little about the Str module but the issue here is how can i add couples or triplets per example of (int*char*int) to the list

Comment: for the 1st comment : when you compile your code, link it with the pkg str (ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg str yourappli.native).